# How to make one field Dependent on other field's value in meteor autoform?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mongoose-schema, meteor-autoform

i'm new to meteor and i want to **create a form in which the value of one field decides the value of another field in the autoform**. Let us take setup types as "A","B",and "C", so when I select "A" a autoform will be loaded. I have made this form as generic i.e it will be displayed for all A,B,and C.

```
{{#each users}}
        {{> afQuickField name='userEmail' value=userEmail readOnly=true }}
        {{> afQuickField name='Setup' value=type readOnly=true}}  
        {{> afQuickField name='Profile' options='allowed' }}
        {{> afQuickField name='Purpose' }}
        {{> afQuickField name='count' options='allowed' }}
        {{> afQuickField name='PackageDirectory' options='allowed'  }}
        {{> afQuickField name="logName" options=LogName }}
 {{/each}}
```

The count options should be:
1. For "A" count options should be 9,11,12.
2. For "B" it's 1.
3. For "C" it's 5.
In schema I have written code like this

```
Setup:{
        type: String,
        label:"Setup",
        optional:false,
       defaultValue:type
      },
 count:{
        type: String,
        label:"No. Of count",
         optional: true,
        allowedValues:["9","11","12"],
        autoform:{
          afFieldInput:{
            firstOption:"(Select the count)"
          }
        }
  }
```

So when i select setup "A" i should get the three dropdown options and when i click "B" and "C" i should get the default value as 1 and 5 respectively.
Can anyone give solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getFieldValue` to get a particular field's value, and based on it return a set of `option` or `defaultValue` from the template helper.
Documentation is found [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#getting-current-field-values)

So in accordance with your code:

**form.html:**

```
    ...
{{#autoForm id="sampleFormID" ... ... }}
    {{> afQuickField name='Setup' value=type readOnly=true}}  
     {{> afQuickField name='count' options=allowedOptionHelper defaultValue=defaultValueHelper }}
    ...

{{/autoForm}}
```

**form.js**

```
Template.templateName.helpers({

    allowedOptionsHelper: function() {
        if (AutoForm.getFieldValue('Setup', 'sampleFormID') === 'A') {
            return [{label:"9", value:"9"},{label:"11",value:"11"},{label:"12", value:"12"}];
            else
            if (AutoForm.getFieldValue('Setup', 'sampleFormID') === 'B') {
                // return the options for B
            } else if (AutoForm.getFieldValue('Setup', 'sampleFormID') === 'C')) {
            // return the options for C
        }
    },

    defaultValueHelper: function() {
        if (AutoForm.getFieldValue('Setup', 'sampleFormID') === 'A') {
            return 11 //or whatever the defaultValue is;
        }
        //likewise for options B and C
    }

});
```

**schema.js**

```
...
...
 count:{
        type: String,
        label:"No. Of count",
         optional: true,
        autoform:{
          afFieldInput:{
            firstOption:"(Select the count)"
          }
        }
  }
...
...
```

Comment: I have modified the code as u suggested, but when i select the setup as "A" i dont get the dropdown in count field.

Comment: Are you not seeing the dropdown field itself? or are you not seeing the dropdown values. If it's the latter, Probably something that's gotta do with the return type. Can you put in console.log statements before the return statements to see if it's actually returning anything. Also, i've just noticed a type mismatch I'd done with the count schema type. I've fixed it.

Comment: I'm not seeing both the values and dropdown, i have checked the return value, as much as i understood what you mentioned is correct. But it's not working in this case. The default values are getting set in the count field.

Comment: You accepted this answer. So I take it that you figured out how to get it to work? What was done?

Comment: Yes i have accepted this answer, but i still didn't get it working. can please help me get it working?. I have mentioned the problem in previous comments. I tried all combination for return values. but the drop down option for count "A" is not coming up. But the default values are set.

Comment: Upload your template, helper and schema somewhere and link back here. Let's talk a look when possible